# Why is jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut not working when I click the navigation button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The content from "about-goal" is not showing upon clicking this navigation button. I need to show the "about-goal" content when clicking the *About Me* button and also for homepage to show up on the same page when clicking *Home* button. Please help.

PS: I'm a beginner to this, just attempting to create my first website. Thanks much!

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
                $('a').click(function(){
                    //alert("i am click");
                    var selected = $(this);
                    $('a').removeClass('active');
                    $(selected).addClass('active');

                });

                var $(a) = $('.a'),
                $b = $('.b'),
                $c = $('.c'),
                $d = $('.d'),
                $home = $('.home'),
                $aboutGoal = $('.aboutGoal');


                $a.click(function(){
                    $home.fadeIn();
                    $aboutGoal.fadeOut();

                });

                $b.click(function(){
                    $home.fadeOut();
                    $aboutGoal.fadeIn();

                });
            });
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="b"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
  <li class="c"><a href="#">My Gallery</a></li>
  <li class="d"><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="aboutGoal">

  <div class="about-me">

    <h2>MY NAME IS...</h2>
    <p class="p1">My name is... , 23 yrs. Old. I’m an aspiring web developer who loves everything about the web. I've lived in lots of different places and have worked in lots of different jobs. I’m excited to bring my life experience to the process of building fantastic
      looking websites.</p>
    <p class="p2">I’ve been a Service Desk Engineer in IBM and am a life-long learner who's always interested in expanding my skills.</p>


  </div>

  <div class="goals">
    <h2>MY GOALS...</h2>
    <p>I want to master the process of building web sites and increase my knowledge, skills and abilities in:</p>
    <ul class="skills">
      <li>HTML</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
      <li>JavaScript</li>
      <li>PHP</li>
      <li>jQuery</li>
      <li>Photo Editing</li>
      <li>Video Editing</li>
    </ul>
    <p>I’d like to work for a web design firm helping clients create an impressive online presence.</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have attempted ?

Comment: you think we have superpower and we know your code without sharing it,

Comment: Yes, if you could show us the html (or a small snippet of it) and some javascript. Then that would be great. Or you can use jsfiddle which works well with javascript code

Comment: Sorry I edited my post a while ago.

Comment: What are you trying to do here `var $(a)`? Also, `$about - goal.fadeOut();` and `$about - goal.fadeIn();`?

Comment: Turnip, I am trying to hide content from *about-goal* class upon clicking the Home button which is "a" class, so that homepage would appear only. actually they are on the same page, it's like navigating on the same page.

Comment: When I edited your post the `$about-goal` was automatically changed to `$about - goal`. You can not use `-` in JavaScript variable names. use `$aboutGoal` or similar. `$(a)` should presumably be `$a`.

Comment: just an idea:`$('a.active').removeClass('active');` would be a little cleaner so it only touches the active links and not all the links

Comment: Can you also post your code for the `about-goal` content section? Just the menu really isn't enough to help.

Comment: `$about-goal` is not a valid variable name, there should be a nice error message in the console. *"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"*

Comment: I tried to change the class name from *about-goal* to *aboutGoal*. but still not working

Comment: @disinfor I edited my post with the whole code for *aboutGoal*

Comment: It isn't the _class_ name that needs to change. It is the _variable_ name. `$(a)` is also not a valid variable name.

Comment: @Turnip I also change the class name since it is the one that I declare as variable name for the whole *aboutGoal* class content

Comment: Sorry for that I'll try to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have a typo with `var $(a) = $('.a')`change it to `var $a = $('.a'),`

you don't need to make a click event for every link

**you can do something like this**

give every link a `PageSection` property  set its value to be the class of the sections you want to hide/show

also give it same class `.nav` so we can write only one click event

```
<li pageSection="aboutGoal" class="nav">
```

put  every page section div inside a container div so we can fade them all together  when  clicking a link

```
<div id="Pages">
```

then use this click event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //view only home section first time
  $("#Pages").children().hide();
  $(".Home").show();

  //when clicking  on a  li element with class nav
  $("li.nav").click(function () {
    //fadout every div  inside Pages div
    $("#Pages").children().fadeOut();
    // FadeIn  element with class  is the same name as the pageSection property from the Li we clicked
    $("." + $(this).attr("pageSection")).fadeIn();
    //remove active class for every li element with class nav
    $("li.nav").removeClass("active");
    //add active class for the li element we clicked
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

live example:
https://codepen.io/vkv88/pen/gOaLgrj?editors=0010

Comment: Updated:   you should hide everything when visiting page first time except Home section